# Call to undefined function getClientOriginalName() in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, undefined-function

I want to use the function `getClientOriginalName()` for making a new name for the photo I take from the user. But as I said before, it displays an error that says that this function is undefined.

```php
$pic = $request->photo;
$newPic = time().$pic.getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method getClientOriginal name exists on the UploadedFile instance. To get the instance you should get by the file() method from $request object

```php
$pic = $request->file('photo');
$newPic = time().$pic->getClientOriginalName();
```